# Locally redefine cleveref’s reference name for chapters

Tags: environments, appendices, cleveref, grouping, appendix

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \crefname{chapter}{appendix}{appendices}%
    %\Crefname{chapter}{Appendix}{Appendices}%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \crefname{chapter}{chapter}{chapters}%
    %\Crefname{chapter}{Chapters}{Chapters}%
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Reference to~regular chapter: \cref{chp:regular_chapter}.

    \noindent Reference to~appendix chapter: \cref{chp:appendix_chapter}.

    \chapter{Regular chapter} \label{chp:regular_chapter}

    Regular chapter text.

    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Appendix chapter} \label{chp:appendix_chapter}

        Appendix chapter text.
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

It results in the following output:

[image: Actual result]

While the result is desired to be as below:

[image: Desired result]

I wonder how the above attempt to locally redefine `cleveref`’s name for chapters references can be fixed to work as intended.

In general, I need a solution to use `\crefname` macro within a local scope.  
Adding `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` did not help.

As an additional improvement, the original reference name for chapters might be stored at first and restored after the end of `appendices` environment (instead of the `chapter`/`chapters` strings pair hard-coded in the MWE).

Answer (score 1):

Package `cleveref` redefines the switch `\appendix`. If you add this command (with or without the `appendices` environment) you will get the desired references in your MWE. But there is no command to switch back to regular chapters references.

A solution is using the optional argument of `label`. This additional optional argument is provided by `cleveref`, too:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\noindent Reference to regular chapter: \cref{chp:regular_chapter}.

\noindent Reference to appendix chapter: \cref{chp:appendix_chapter}.

\noindent Referece to another regular chapter: \cref{chp:another}.

\chapter{Regular chapter} \label{chp:regular_chapter}
Regular chapter text.

\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Appendix chapter}
  \label[appendix]{chp:appendix_chapter}% <- changed (optional argument added)
  Appendix chapter text.
\end{appendices}

\chapter{Another regular chapter}\label{chp:another}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After [esdd’s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43317/esdd) [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502692) I managed to do it in a bit more automated way:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Reference to~regular chapter: \cref{chp:regular_chapter}.

    \noindent Reference to~appendix chapter:  \cref{chp:appendix_chapter}.

    \noindent Reference to~another regular chapter:  \cref{chp:another_regular_chapter}.

    \chapter{Regular chapter} \label{chp:regular_chapter}

    Regular chapter text.

    \begin{appendices}
        \appendix
        \chapter{Appendix chapter} \label{chp:appendix_chapter}

        Appendix chapter text.
    \end{appendices}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}

    \chapter{Another regular chapter} \label{chp:another_regular_chapter}

    Another regular chapter text.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]